# Use datagridview cell value from form 1 to filter datagridview 2 in form 2

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2019

I have 2 different datagridview (1. Client List 2. Payment History of that Client) in two different forms. When I click the client from form 1 I want to use his clientID to filter the datagridview on Form2 problem is when I use `WHERE` as a query it doesn't show the table, if I remove `WHERE` all of the payments in the payment table will show.

[image: Client List]
here's the code for when clicking the row from form 1

```
ElseIf colName = "colViewPayment" Then

        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = datagridviewClient.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim fname As String
        Dim lname As String
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbtClients WHERE ClientID = @ClientID")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientID", row.Cells("ClientID").Value)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                sdr.Read()
                fname = sdr("ClientFirstName")
                lname = sdr("ClientLastName")
                frmLoanerPaymentHistoryBunifu.NameR.Text = fname + " " + lname
                frmLoanerPaymentHistoryBunifu.CpNo.Text = sdr("ClientMobileNumber").ToString()
                frmLoanerPaymentHistoryBunifu.ClientID.Text = sdr("ClientID").ToString()

            End Using
            con.Close()
            frmLoanerPaymentHistoryBunifu.ShowDialog()


        End Using
```

[image]
Here is the code for populating the datagrid in Payment History Form (form2)

```
Private Sub BindGrid()

    Dim CID As String = ClientID.Text
    Dim x As Integer = Convert.ToInt64(CID)

    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PaymentTable WHERE ClientID = '" + ClientID.Text + "'", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Using dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)

                pDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = False

                'Add Columns
                pDataGrid.Columns(0).Name = "PID"
                pDataGrid.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "PaymentID"

                pDataGrid.Columns(1).Name = "CID"
                pDataGrid.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "ClientID"

                pDataGrid.Columns(2).Name = "Pdate"
                pDataGrid.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "PDate"

                pDataGrid.Columns(3).Name = "Pamt"
                pDataGrid.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "PAmt"

                pDataGrid.Columns(4).Name = "Pren"
                pDataGrid.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "ReloanDate"

                pDataGrid.Columns(5).Name = "Pcol"
                pDataGrid.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "PColl"

                pDataGrid.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually know how to get a Value from a datagridview and already did, by passing the name and mobile number of the client, I also know how to filter a datagridview which I have already done as said in my post. My problem is when I'm filtering there is no result. As shown in the image the datagrid remains blank.

passed the client ID data from the datagrid to a label in form 2 and tried converting it to a integer. but still no result. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Is `ClientID` actually a string type (as a Column type value, I mean)? Why don't you use `Parameters.Add()` instead of `Parameters.AddWithValue()`, so you need to specify the correct data type and use Parameters also in the second query?

Comment: ClientID is int type in the database, as it is the primary key in the Client table, and a foreign key in Payments Table. It is in a one-to-many relationship

Comment: Well, you're passing a string: `(...) WHERE ClientID = ' ← (...) + "'"`. Use `Parameters.Add()` (also in the second query).

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", frmClientList.datagridviewClient.Row.Cells("ClientID").Value)` when using that I get an error saying Row is not a member

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write something like: `frmClientList.datagridviewClient.CurrentRow.Cells("ClientID").Value`? Btw, **specify the data type**.